# Multiplayer Peer-To-Peer position interpolation

Tags: c#, networking, unity3d

I have coded this movement interpolation for Unity3d using Photon.

OnPhotonSerializeView gets called at the tickrate.

Any kind of criticism/improvement suggestions are welcome. I tried to make the code as plain as possible because I don't see this as something that should be over-engineered because it is rather algorithmic in nature.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerInterpolation : MonoBehaviour {
    Queue<Vector3> positions = new Queue<Vector3>();
    Queue<Quaternion> rotations = new Queue<Quaternion>();
    Queue<int> frameNumbers = new Queue<int>();
    static int amountBuffered = 1;
    static float oneTickTime = 1.0f / Settings.tickRate;

    PhotonView photonView;
    int localSentFrameNumber = 0;
    int lastReceivedFrameNumber = -1;
    int lastFrameNumberMovedTowards = 0;

    int expectedExecuteFrameNumber = 0; //An estimation of what frame number should be executing at this time.
    float expectedExecuteFrameNumberLastExecutedTime = 0;

    Vector3 moveTowards;
    float moveTowardsSpeed = 1.0f;
    bool moveInProgress = false;

    void Start() {
        photonView = gameObject.GetComponent<PhotonView>();
        moveTowards = transform.position;
    }

    void Update() {
        if (photonView.isMine) return;

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, moveTowards, moveTowardsSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, moveTowards)) < 0.001f) {
            moveInProgress = false;
        } else {
            moveInProgress = true;
        }

        if (expectedExecuteFrameNumberLastExecutedTime + oneTickTime < Time.realtimeSinceStartup) {
            expectedExecuteFrameNumber++;
            expectedExecuteFrameNumberLastExecutedTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        }

        if (frameNumbers.Count > 0 && ((frameNumbers.Peek() + amountBuffered <= lastReceivedFrameNumber) || frameNumbers.Peek() <= expectedExecuteFrameNumber - amountBuffered)) {
            if (lastReceivedFrameNumber - frameNumbers.Peek() > amountBuffered) {
                int trimUntil = lastReceivedFrameNumber - amountBuffered;
                while (frameNumbers.Peek() < trimUntil) {
                    positions.Dequeue();
                    rotations.Dequeue();
                    frameNumbers.Dequeue();
                }
            }

            Vector3 position = positions.Dequeue();
            Quaternion rotation = rotations.Dequeue();
            int frameNumber = frameNumbers.Dequeue();

            if (moveInProgress == true) {
                transform.position = moveTowards;
            }

            float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, position);
            moveTowards = position;
            moveTowardsSpeed = distance * (frameNumber - lastFrameNumberMovedTowards) / oneTickTime;

            lastFrameNumberMovedTowards = frameNumber;

            expectedExecuteFrameNumber = frameNumber;
            expectedExecuteFrameNumberLastExecutedTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        }
    }

    void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info) {
        if (stream.isWriting) {
            stream.SendNext(transform.position);
            stream.SendNext(transform.rotation);
            stream.SendNext(localSentFrameNumber++);
        } else {
            positions.Enqueue((Vector3)stream.ReceiveNext());
            rotations.Enqueue((Quaternion)stream.ReceiveNext());
            int frameNumber = (int)stream.ReceiveNext();
            frameNumbers.Enqueue(frameNumber);
            lastReceivedFrameNumber = frameNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend you always write access modifiers for class members and for classes itself. It will make code more clear and understandable. So instead of

> ```
> Queue<Vector3> positions = new Queue<Vector3>();
> Queue<Quaternion> rotations = new Queue<Quaternion>();
> ...
> void Start() { ... }
> ```

write

```
private Queue<Vector3> positions = new Queue<Vector3>();
private Queue<Quaternion> rotations = new Queue<Quaternion>();
...

private void Start() { ... }
```

Also these queues are not supposed to be changed so mark them with `readonly` keyword:

```
private readonly Queue<Vector3> positions = new Queue<Vector3>();
...
```

---

It is a matter of taste but it is more common for C# to place opening curly braces on the next line:

```
private void Start()
{
    photonView = gameObject.GetComponent<PhotonView>();
    moveTowards = transform.position;
}
```

---

This code

> ```
> if (Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, moveTowards)) < 0.001f) {
>     moveInProgress = false;
> } else {
>     moveInProgress = true;
> }
> ```

can be simplified to

```
moveInProgress = Mathf.Abs(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, moveTowards)) >= 0.001f;
```

Also it would be better to declare `0.001f` as named constant like

```
private const float DistanceEpsilon = 0.001f;
```

---

You should definitely rewrite these conditions:

> ```
> if (frameNumbers.Count > 0 && ((frameNumbers.Peek() + amountBuffered <= lastReceivedFrameNumber) || frameNumbers.Peek() <= expectedExecuteFrameNumber - amountBuffered)) {
>     if (lastReceivedFrameNumber - frameNumbers.Peek() > amountBuffered)
> ```

First of all, you use frameNumbers.Peek() multiple times here so store the result of it to variable:

```
var firstFrameNumber = frameNumbers.Peek();
```

I recommend to use `Any` method for checking a collection on emptiness:

```
frameNumbers.Any()
```

instead of

> ```
> frameNumbers.Count > 0
> ```

Thanks @Nikita B for pointing out that `frameNumbers.Any()` should be done before `frameNumbers.Peek()`. In your case you can just return from the method if there are no elements in the `frameNumbers`:

```
if (!frameNumbers.Any())
    return;
```

These conditions

> ```
> frameNumbers.Peek() + amountBuffered <= lastReceivedFrameNumber
> lastReceivedFrameNumber - frameNumbers.Peek() > amountBuffered
> ```

can be written in one form:

```
lastReceivedFrameNumber - frameNumbers.Peek() > amountBuffered
lastReceivedFrameNumber - frameNumbers.Peek() >= amountBuffered
```

Now we see that we can store `lastReceivedFrameNumber - frameNumbers.Peek()` to variable since this expression is used multiple times. So the final form of conditions above will be

```
if (!frameNumbers.Any())
    return;

var firstFrameNumber = frameNumbers.Peek();
var frameNumbersDifference = lastReceivedFrameNumber - firstFrameNumber;

if (frameNumbersDifference >= amountBuffered ||
    firstFrameNumber <= expectedExecuteFrameNumber - amountBuffered)
{
    if (frameNumbersDifference > amountBuffered)
```

Also I recommend to extract all subconditions to methods with appropriate names. It will make your code much more easy to read and understand.

---

Small note: you don't need to write `== true` or `== false` when checking value of bool variable. This

> ```
> if (moveInProgress == true) {
> ```

should be rewritten as

```
if (moveInProgress)
{
```

Comment: Rgearding `.Any()` vs. `Count > 0` I prefer the later because it only checks the `Count` property. If we talk about the extension method `Count()` I prefer `.Any()` like you.

Comment: @Heslacher Do you use `Count > 0` to save a couple of microseconds or this expression is more clear for you? As for me I use `Any` for every `IEnumerable` to make my code consistent between different applications and for easy replacement of a collection with another class, and it looks prettier for me :) But I never wrote performance critical apps where `Any` can increase time of execution of some code.

Comment: `frameNumbers.Peek()` will throw if `Queue` is empty. You should check`frameNumbers.Any()` first, and only then peek.

Comment: Hey, OP here. Can't login into that account because it says that a user with that email already exists which is this account... But anyway.

I'd just like to say, thank you very much for all of the comments!

Comment: Ah there, managed to merge my accounts and accepted your answer.

Comment: You are right about `.Any()` is more clear. Maybe I should consider changing my prefereneces.;-)

Answer (score 2):

One small note...

> ```
> static int amountBuffered = 1;
> static float oneTickTime = 1.0f / Settings.tickRate;
> ```

If you define contants then you should decorate them either with the `const` keyword or the `readonly` one. By doing so you clearly inform that this value naver changes and you also cannot overwrite it by accident.

Overall your code isn't bad. I find you use very good and meaningful names, early returns, not too much nesting. Just a few more helper variables like [@Maxim suggested](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/173047/59161) and it's fine.